# ZSH Git prompt status stays always visible for a non-git directory

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

ZSH shell shows Git prompt status (master [?]) even if a directory isn't a git directory.
What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

[image]

My .zshrc file:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

export ZSH=/Users/m3rkus/.oh-my-zsh

ZSH_THEME="spaceship"

plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you are not in a git directory? What is the output of  `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`?

Comment: Please try `ls -al .git` and see if there's any git folder

Answer (score 1):

One of the higher level folder has probably a `.git` folder in it.

You can use @Adaephon suggested command to find where it is:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```